# different result while nmap scan a subnet

Tags: networking, nmap

while running:
nmap -n -PN -sT -T4  -p 445,139 10.0.40.0/24
i get:

Interesting ports on 10.0.40.6:
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
139/tcp **filtered** netbios-ssn
445/tcp **filtered** microsoft-ds

if I specifically scan a single ip

nmap -n -PN -sT -T4  -p 445,139 10.0.40.6
Interesting ports on 10.0.40.6:
PORT    STATE SERVICE
139/tcp **open**  netbios-ssn
445/tcp **open**  microsoft-ds

***why there is a difference?***

*Note*:
if I omit the -sT from the sub net scan I get:
PORT    STATE SERVICE
139/tcp **open**  netbios-ssn
445/tcp **open**  microsoft-ds

Answer (score 0):

They should be identical. I am thinking that maybe it has something to do with latency/scan timeout. Are the results the same if you try a different scan type, and a slower scan time?

Comment: thanks @gerryk , i thought so to , but isn't nmap suppose to handle slow connection , running the command from the same subnet being tested result in open connection found

Answer (score 0):

-sT is an ACK scan. Well it is in some way trying to stay under a remote log's radar... So the router might detect that you are doing something weird and is filtering you out. Perhaps you could either drop (-sT) from your options or use a SYN scan(-sS).